# sources for all infinite series?

Tags: sequences-and-series, reference-request

I'm looking for a source for all of the known infinite series, if such a source exists.

The following site is the best source that I have found so far, but I do not know if it is complete and it does not seem to have a way to contact in order to add additional series.  I am hoping that there is a better source--something like the OEIS provides for sequences.  Any suggestions?  Thanks.

http://pi.physik.uni-bonn.de/~dieckman/InfProd/InfProd.html

For instance, how does one know if an infinite series is new or already exists?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by 'known'? That it's appeared as an example in some textbook, or some final from a reputable institution?

Comment: I suppose so; I thought there may be a list of them all, so that people could check different relations or look for similarities between series, and to check if a 'new' series has not been already found.  For instance, the infinite product series linking the logarithmic spiral at thirty degree (e^(pi/6)) with the golden ratio.  As this series appears to not be in any books or internet sources including those suggested here, how might one encourage the authors, publishers, or website hosters to include the series in the next edition, or to somehow make it publicly available to those interested.

Answer (score 4):

I'd doubt you'd find *all* known infinite series in any text, but a very famous and comprehensive treatise is the one by [Gradshteyn and Ryzhik](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0122947606).

Comment: The book appears to be copyrighted material. The presence of illegal pirate stuff on the net is unfortunate (I think). Providing links to this material sanctions it, in some sense. Is there any site policy on this? Should be a meta question, maybe.

Comment: I have edited to give a more suitable link. It was not my intention to link to "pirated" material; it just happened to be the first hit on Google. But feel free to raise the meta question anyway.

Comment: I looked on meta, and there has been some discussion of this and related issues. I don't see any clear policy, but, to be honest, I got bored pretty quickly, and only skimmed through the discussion. But, regardless of any policy, I make my living from intellectual property (books and software), so I appreciate your changing the link so quickly. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

L. B. W. Jolley, Summation of Series, is a very useful compendium.